# Is there any python web app framework that provides database abstraction layer for SQL and NoSQL?

Tags: python, sql, database, google-app-engine, nosql

Is it even possible to create an abstraction layer that can accommodate relational and non-relational databases? The purpose of this layer is to minimize repetition and allows a web application to use any kind of database by just changing/modifying the code in one place (ie, the abstraction layer). The part that sits on top of the abstraction layer must not need to worry whether the underlying database is relational (SQL) or non-relational (NoSQL) or whatever new kind of database that may come out later in the future.

Comment: Is this an effect of not being able to wrap your head around BigTable?

Comment: There are all kind of NoSQL db's.

Comment: Existing ORMs try to make an RDBMS look like an OODB, more or less.  Every one I've seen still often requires you to know it's an RDBMS and code against it as such.  I'd think that with such very different storage architectures, you'll take a serious hit to performance, or abstraction, or both.  Certainly I've not seen it done well for RDBMSs, and not for lack of trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers. To summarize the answers, currently only web2py and Django supports this kind of abstraction.

It is not about a SQL-NoSQL holy grail, using abstraction can make the apps more flexible. Lets assume that you started a project using NoSQL, and then later on you need to switch over to SQL. It is desirable that you only make changes to the codes in a few spots instead of all over the place. For some cases, it does not really matter whether you store the data in a relational or non-relational db. For example, storing user profiles, text content for dynamic page, or blog entries.
I know there must be a trade off by using the abstraction, but my question is more about the existing solution or technical insight, instead of the consequences.

Answer (score 2):

There's [a Summer of Code project](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/branches/soc2010/query-refactor) going on right now to add non-relational support to Django's ORM. It seems to be going well and chances are good that it will be merged into core in time for Django 1.3.

Answer (score 2):

You could use stock Django and Django-nonrel ( http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel ) together to get a quite unified experience. Some limits apply, read docs carefully though, remembering Spolsky's "All abstractions are leaky".

Answer (score 1):

Yo may also check web2py, they support relational databases and GAE on the core.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding App Engine, all existing attempts limit you in some way (web2py doesn't support transactions or namespaces and probably many other stuff, for example). If you plan to work with GAE, use what GAE provides and forget looking for a SQL-NoSQL holy grail. Existing solutions are inevitably limited and affect performance negatively.